# Java assert not printing its "reason"

Tags: java, assert

When I run the following code with "java -ea A", the assertion correction fires, but I see no mention of the second parameter.

```
public class A {
    public A() {
        assert 1==2, "We have a problem";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = new A();
    }
}
```

Can't seem to find the answer to this anywhere, what am I missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax should be:

```
assert 1==2 : "We have a problem";
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept this answer if it resolved your problem.